# unique visitor counter from 2 pages

Tags: php, html, cookies, google-analytics, unique

i'm doing a PTC (PayToClick) website, which you get paid for the number of clicks you have on your shrinked url.

i want to know if the user clicking your url is unique, if he clicked only once on your url AND he saw the ad only 1 time.

i was thinking of 2 methods to do so, but i dont know what is the best, or there might be another way that is better.

1. get the info from google analytics for the ad, so i will have the number of unique views of the ad, but i can't find a way to know for sure what user got what number of unique views.

lets say i have 2 ads that each have 100 unique views, i have 2 users who are publishing both of the ads, i don't know how to know if user1 got 60 unique views of ad1 and user2 got 40 views and viceversa.

2. i can use cookies and ip address but cookies can be deleted and ip can be changed, and i really dont want to use it, because i will have to code a check to see if that user got too many clicks from the same city etc, and i might lose users.

Any thoughts on that? did i forgot something??

Answer (score 0):

I use a website called statcounter.com for Web analytics it may be what your looking for hope that helped :) it let's you drill down into individual page details